# I can change the pointer's function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

In script languages, such as Perl and Python, I can change function in run-time. I can do something in C by changing the pointer to a function?

Something like:

```
void fun1() {
    printf("fun1\n");
}

void fun2() {
    printf("fun2\n");
}

int main() {
    fun1 = &fun2;
    fun1(); // print "fun2"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why not just run it and find out?

Comment: You need to use function pointers.

Comment: This is an example of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you please tell us the root problem that you actually try to solve?

Comment: @Quirliom It does not work. The code has only to describe what I want do.

Comment: @leppie I want to learn to do in C, studies purposes

Comment: `fun1 = &fun2;`..you need more than that. :-)

Comment: Then read the comment from @CoolGuy, and do a search for e.g. *c function pointers*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can't do **that**.

You can regard fun1 as a placeholder for the fixed entry point of that function.

The semantic you are looking for is that from `fun1=&fun2;` point on every call to `fun1` causes `fun2` to be called.

`fun1` is a value not a variable. In the same way in the statement `int x=1;` `x` is a variable and `1` is a value.

Your code makes no more sense than thinking `1=2;` will compile and from that point on `x=x+1;` will result in `x` being incremented by 2.

Just because `fun1` is an identifier doesn't mean it's a variable let alone assignable.

Answer (score 6):

Yes; You can and this is the simple program which will help you in understanding this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void fun1() {
    printf("fun1\n");
 }

 void fun2() {
    printf("fun2\n");
 }

 int main() {
       void (*fun)() = &fun1;
       fun(); // print "fun1"
       fun = &fun2;
       fun(); // print "fun2"
       return 0; 
 }
```

### Output

```
➤ ./a.exe
fun1
fun2
```

Comment: The `&` isn't needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can't change fun1, but you can declare a function pointer (not a function, only a pointer to a function).

```
void (*fun)();
fun = fun1;
fun(); /* calls fun1 */
fun = fun2;
fun(); /* calls fun2 */
```

As you might have noticed it is not necessary to take the address of fun1/fun2 explicitely, you can omit the address-of operator '&'.

Comment: The `&` isn't needed.

Comment: @alk I know, but: a) it does not hurt and b) in C++ you need the '&', so why not write it explicitely?